# Git plugin for jenkins always fetches all branches

Tags: git, jenkins

No matter what options I use to the Jenkins git plugin it always pulls down all branches:

```
git fetch --no-tags --progress ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:7999/project/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --depth=5
```

Instead of `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` I was expecting it to just do something like: `+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`. Configuration is as per screen shot.

[image: Jenkins scm configuration]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the 'Advanced' button under the credentials field, and then update as per screen shot.

[image: Jenkins configuration]

In the screen shot I have used 'master' as the branch I want to fetch, if you are using a different branch then update as appropriate.