# Gitlab-jenkins webhook triggers build with wrong branch

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I've been trying to setup a build-trigger with a gitlab web-hook to my Jenkins freestyle project,

For that,

- In Jenkins, added gitlab connection, added the ssh url and specified the branch I need to build in the `git` plugin's `Branches to build` section,
  [image: Git plugin branch specifier]

  Also, with the `Gitlab` plugin installed, opt for the `Build Triggeres` > `gitlab webhook url`
- As the next step, created an outgoing webhook in gitlab and added the url,
  [image: Gitlab webhook with branch specified]

Now the webhook works and the build gets triggered on repo changes,
But the problem is **Jenkins Builds the Project on different Branch when it gets triggered from web hook**,

What I've done so far,

- On checking further, when there is changes in multiple branches ie, `origin/master`, `origin/feature`, `origin/test`, The first one in the list ie the master getting build instead of the specified `test` branch.
- When built from jenkins directly, It pulls the correct branch, no issues there,
- I've modified the configuration as per this [stack-overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50123616/12167598). such as mentioning the 'refspec' and adding advanced clone behaviours and shallow clone, but nothing seems to work,

comparing the git commands executed at the time of a direct jenkins build and a gitlab webhook-triggered build shows this difference,(with the refspec modifications)

```sh
 # on successful build
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress --depth=5 -- git@gitlab.com:<project_name>.git +refs/heads/test:refs/remotes/origin/test # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/test^{commit} # timeout=10

# when triggered via webhook (it switches to master at last)
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress --depth=5 -- git@gitlab.com:<project_name>.git +refs/heads/test:refs/remotes/origin/test # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.com:<project_name>.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/test:refs/remotes/origin/test # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
 > git rev-parse remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
```

All branches with changes are showing in the build section instead of the `test` branch,
which is the only branch I need this project to pull from the remote,

Using Jenkins version `2.303.3` JDK 8, plugins version Gitlab: `1.5.22`, Git : `4.10.0,`

Can someone suggest any solution for this,

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it is building the wrong branch only at the time of testing web-hook from gitlab,

On a regular change, the desired branch is build as specified in Jenkins and in gitlab, be sure to use the branch filter in gitlab if doing like this,

It is evident that when testing the web-hook, gitlab sends triggers for all branches that got changes, what happens in Jenkins I assume is it builds the default branch when receiving such triggers,